# How to repair or update my messages in chat?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat

When I typed a message with wrong spelling and posted it , How to repair it at later time ?
I got **talk in chat** privileges after getting my reputation 20. So , I am a newbie on chat , I had chat with another guy via my questions comments "*let us continue this discussion in chat* ". But I don't know how to update my messages.

I really want to do is I want to update my messages at any time or just one day.

Comment: Even Skype doesn't let you edit messages that are more than an hour old.

Comment: @ BoltClock's a Unicorn♦ , yes you right . I can't update my yesterday  skype's message at now.

Comment: This could cause problems later on. If you were given the ability to edit your messages, then a significant change to a message, would render the reply to that message already posted useless and this could lead to a lot of conflicts, because chats are mostly used by users to clarify the questions in detail(read *Chameleon questions*). And we certainly don't want to encourage that. And seems my friend *Michael* just explained this scenario in the answer(very nicely) :)

Comment: @R.J , I disagree.. just only your opinions ? I don't think so , we can delete or update our questions , comments but why not in chat ?

Comment: You cannot update the comments after a certain grace time period. Have you tried doing that?! Just as an example, I posted my previous comment 29 mins ago. If I could edit that now, I could change it to something like *You're awesome* and your reply to it, *I disagree* would sound so odd. That's the point I'm trying to make here.

Comment: @R.J , but can delete comments and write new one . Tell me chats can also edit in certain time period.

Comment: *Point no.1* in the answer below clearly states - **If it's been less than two minutes, you can edit your message**.

Comment: @R.J ,@michaelb958 , Really ? pls guide me how to . I am really want to know. How to figure it out ? Oh ! how to update my message in less than two minutes.

Comment: Oh ! awesome ... my question get rich downvotes :) ..I don't care it. I need my answer. Why ? my question obeys rules of asking question and  I think really simple ;). I will meet you again at next question.

Comment: "On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement" ([help/whats-meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta))

Comment: @ gnat , nice reason. very thanks to u. yes I agree. I will wait for agree or disagree. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. If it's been less than two minutes, you can edit your message.
2. Ask a friendly moderator - they can edit any message at any time *if they feel like it*. (So make your case well, and make sure it *must* be fixed.)
3. Otherwise: Sorry, you're out of luck.

## Edit to respond to [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

I can't respond to this officially (not being an SE developer), but I think it's a bad idea. Imagine some random chat room:

> **FooUser** I like caring for kittens

Three minutes pass:

> **BarUser** @FooUser Yeah, I like that too

An hour later, FooUser edits just before BazUser ♦ wanders in:

> **FooUser** I like brutally murdering SE employees
>   **BarUser** @FooUser Yeah, I like that too
>   ***BazUser ♦*** kicks both users

BarUser is instantly suspended from chat for expressing their love for caring for kittens.

Comment: As you described , I want to get this feature. why not users can edit their message at any times ?

Comment: I don't agree entirely yours , If you can said that I also can show useful examples.. When chatting two guys , for instance :one guy question asker and another answerer. I am sure , they will respect each others and they will use polite messages. But when something is going wrong when typed.. they need to describe additional messages as "sorry previous message got wrong . I mean...".

Comment: In chat rooms , sometimes we need to describe sample codes. If so, we need to edit them in another text editors and when we confirmed, we must post them .

Comment: The good half was never the problem. It was the bad half, and the bad things which could happen far out-weigh the good ones.

Comment: @Cataclysm And? I routinely use external text editors to draft code, and corrections in subsequent messages are hardly frowned upon.

Comment: "If it's been less than two minutes, you can edit your message." Pls guide me how to figure it out. That may be my answer.

Comment: @Cataclysm Place cursor in (empty) message composition textbox, press your up arrow key.

Comment: @michaelb958 ,ok sir. pls update your answer as like it. I mean append guide to update message.

Comment: @Cataclysm [It's in the chat FAQ, you know.](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#talk)

Comment: @michaelb958, yeah , I found it by your url .Thanks in advance sir. Thanks for your valuable times.